# Unable to parse jsonp response from geocode site

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am totally new to JavaScript, trying to get JSONP geocoding data from geocoding.geo.census.gov into a website. The response looks something like that (from chrome), only the first few keys are shown:

JSONPCallback({"result":{"input":{"address":{"address":"333 e 33th st austin tx"},"vintage":{"isDefault":true,"vintageName":"Current_Current","id":"4","vintageDescription":"Current Vintage - Current Benchmark"},"benchmark":{"isDefault":false,"id":"4","benchmarkName":"Public_AR_Current","benchmarkDescription":"Public Address Ranges - Current Benchmark"}}...............

This is the code I'm using:

```
var jsonp = {
callbackCounter: 0,

fetch: function(url, callback) {
    var fn = 'JSONPCallback_' + this.callbackCounter++;
    window[fn] = this.evalJSONP(callback);
    url = url.replace('=JSONPCallback', '=' + fn);

    var scriptTag = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptTag.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
},

evalJSONP: function(callback) {
    return function(data) {
        var validJSON = false;
    if (typeof data == "string") {
        try {validJSON = JSON.parse(data);} catch (e) {
            /*invalid JSON*/}
    } else {
        validJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        window.console && console.warn('response data was not a JSON string');
    }

        if (validJSON) {
            callback(validJSON);
        } else {
            throw("JSONP call returned invalid or empty JSON");
        }
    }
}
```

}

then:

```
{console.log(Object.keys(data));}  //(or data[0])
```

and all I'm getting in the console is:

response data was not a JSON string

Array[1]0: "result"
  length: 1
  **proto**: Array[0]

I don't understand why all I'm getting is just "result"?

Comment: You don't need to parse the data with JSON.parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
evalJSONP: function(callback) {
    return callback;            
}
```

That should work. If your sample is accurate. Then you don't need to parse the data.

Comment: I'm still only getting 'result'.

Comment: This is code that I found and it was tested with other API's (not written by me). The original example was:    jsonp.fetch(surl, function(data) {console.log(data.data.children[0].data.title)});  instead of my:    jsonp.fetch(surl, function(data) {console.log(Object.keys(data)[0]);});    but data.data.children[0].data.title.input returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Comment: Just tried some different code and it works. I didn't realize until now the site is returning objects within objects..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the old code wasn't working because it was trying to parse an object. Plase correct me if I'm wrong.